# Python: Lambda in Parameter List

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a nice solution to do something like this lambda function in a parameter list?

```
timeout = None

[...]

 response = self.session.post(
        url=self.baseUrl,
        data=str(data),
        headers=headers,
        timeout=lambda: 0 if self.timeout is None else self.timeout
    )
```

I know it throws an exception. But is there a possible solution to do something like this?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing. That code by itself would not throw an exception, it's perfectly valid; but presumably the `post` method is not expecting a callable, so I don't understand why you are passing it one. Why can't you simply do `timeout=0 if self.timeout is None else self.timeout`?

Comment: Agree with @DanielRoseman. You don't seem to gain any advantage here using lambda. Is this your real code or just an example you're using for the question?

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman. It was just an example code. Of course i should do timeout=0 if self.timeout is None else self.timeout . I just was wondering if there is a possibility to use the return of a function in a parameterlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timeout = None

 response = self.session.post(
        url=self.baseUrl,
        data=str(data),
        headers=headers,
        timeout=(lambda: 0 if self.timeout is None else self.timeout)()
    )
```

It is just an inline function works with closures.

Answer (score 0):

If you define `timeout` as class variable, than it is **something determining object's state**. In case where you have to set initial value depending on some condition you can do one of folowing basic things:

1. Initialize it in `__init__`
2. Use [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) and define getter, which returns applicable value.